# parametric integral thought of as change of variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In the video below
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZ5AF5mITnA
At 3:20 he says,

$$\int_c g(x,y)ds = \int_a ^b g(x(t),y(t)) \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}dt$$

where we can think of $\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}$ as the change of variables jacobian.

$$\frac {\partial (x,y)}{\partial t} = det\begin{pmatrix}x'(t)\\y'(t)\end{pmatrix}$$

he states that $$det\begin{pmatrix}x'(t)\\y'(t)\end{pmatrix} = \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}$$

Is this correct, because I thought you could only take the determinant of a square matrix. I feel like its correct to say that we can think of it as a change of variables jacobian however I'm not sure if the reasoning is correct.